# Non-working Menu Built in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, menu

I have been trying to make a basic game with a menu with 10 levels. The level selected is supposed to load when the enter-button is pressed but I get a huge error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GameState.Level1State.init(Level1State.java:29)
at GameState.Level1State.<init>(Level1State.java:78)
at GameState.GameStateManager.loadState(GameStateManager.java:35)
at GameState.GameStateManager.setState(GameStateManager.java:77)
at GameState.LevelSelect.select(LevelSelect.java:82)
at GameState.LevelSelect.keyPressed(LevelSelect.java:121)
at GameState.GameStateManager.keyPressed(GameStateManager.java:95)
at Main.GamePanel.keyPressed(GamePanel.java:115)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GameState.GameStateManager.keyReleased(GameStateManager.java:99)
at Main.GamePanel.keyReleased(GamePanel.java:119)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at       java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the code for where the levels get selected and loaded:

```
package GameState;



public class GameStateManager {
private GameState[] gameStates;
private int currentState;

public static final int NUMGAMESSTATES = 12;
public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
public static final int LEVEL1STATE = 1;
public static final int LEVEL2STATE = 2;
public static final int LEVEL3STATE = 3;
public static final int LEVEL4STATE = 4;
public static final int LEVEL5STATE = 5;
public static final int LEVEL6STATE = 6;
public static final int LEVEL7STATE = 7;
public static final int LEVEL8STATE = 8;
public static final int LEVEL9STATE = 9;
public static final int LEVEL10STATE = 10;
public static final int LEVELSELECT = 11;

public GameStateManager(){
    gameStates = new GameState[NUMGAMESSTATES];

    currentState = MENUSTATE;
    loadState(currentState);
}

public void loadState(int state){
    if (state == MENUSTATE){
        gameStates[state] = new MenuState(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL1STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level1State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL2STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level2State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL3STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level3State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL4STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level4State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL5STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level5State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL6STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level6State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL7STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level7State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL8STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level8State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL9STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level9State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVEL10STATE){
        gameStates[state] = new Level10State(this);
    }
    if(state == LEVELSELECT){
        gameStates[state] = new LevelSelect(this);
    }

}

private void unloadState (int state){
    gameStates[state] = null;
}

public void setState(int state){
    unloadState(currentState);
    currentState = state;
    loadState(currentState);
}

public void update(){
    try{
        gameStates[currentState].update();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g){
    try{
        gameStates[currentState].draw(g);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

public void keyPressed(int k){
    gameStates[currentState].keyPressed(k);
}

public void keyReleased(int k){
    gameStates[currentState].keyReleased(k);
}
}
```

Here is the menu where the levels are chosen by the user. It then goes to the code I posted above:

```
package GameState;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import Main.Background;




public class LevelSelect extends GameState{
private Background bg;

private int currentChoice = 0;
private String[] options = {
        "Level1",
        "Level2",
        "Level3",
        "Level4",
        "Level5",
        "Level6",
        "Level7",
        "Level8",
        "Level9",
        "Level10",
        "Back",
        "Quit"
};

private Color titleColor;
private Font titleFont;

private Font font;

public LevelSelect(GameStateManager gsm){
    this.gsm = gsm;

    try{
        bg = new Background("/Images/achtergrond.png");
        titleColor =  new Color(128, 0, 0);
        titleFont = new Font("Century Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 28);

        font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void init(){}

public void update(){
    //bg.update();
}


public void draw(Graphics2D g){
//draw bg
bg.draw(g);

//draw title
g.setColor(titleColor);
g.setFont(titleFont);
g.drawString("Car Avoider", 25, 70);

//draw menu options
g.setFont(font);
for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    if(i == currentChoice){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else{
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
    g.drawString(options[i],80, 50 + i *15);
}
}

private void select(){
    if(currentChoice == 0){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL1STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 1){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL2STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 2){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL3STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 3){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL4STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 4){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL5STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 5){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL6STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 6){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL7STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 7){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL8STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 8){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL9STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 9){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.LEVEL10STATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 11){
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.MENUSTATE);
    }
    if(currentChoice == 12){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void keyPressed(int k){
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        select();
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        currentChoice--;
        if(currentChoice == -1){
            currentChoice = options.length -1;
        }
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        currentChoice++;
        if(currentChoice == options.length){
            currentChoice = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(int k){}
}
```

here is an example of 1 of the levels. Its a simple game with moving cars from left to right and you have to get to the top but that's not really relevant I  think for the menu. The game did work before I tried implementing the menu.

```
package GameState;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import Character.Player;
import Enemy.Enemy;
import Enemy.Enemy2;
 import Main.Background;

public class Level1State extends GameState {
//variables
private Background bg;
private Enemy enemy;
private Enemy2 enemy2;
public static Player player;
public boolean Explosion = false;

//arraylists
private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;
private ArrayList<Enemy2> enemies2;

public void init() {
    //new enemies
    populateEnemies();
    populateEnemies2();
    enemy.setMoveSpeed(-2);
    enemy2.setMoveSpeed(2);
    //new images and objects
    bg = new Background("/Images/achtergrond2.png");
    enemy = new Enemy("/Images/Square.png");
    enemy2 = new Enemy2("/Images/Square.png");
    player = new Player("/Images/character.png");
}

private void populateEnemies() {
    //new enemies

    enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

    Enemy s;
    Point[] points = new Point[] { 
            new Point(-50, 136), 
            new Point(-100, 76)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        s = new Enemy("/Images/Square.png");
        s.setPosition(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        enemies.add(s);
    }

}

private void populateEnemies2() {
    //new enemies

    enemies2 = new ArrayList<Enemy2>();

    Enemy2 s;
    Point[] points = new Point[] { 
            new Point(450, 106), 
            new Point(400, 46)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        s = new Enemy2("/Images/Square.png");
        s.setPosition(points[i].x, points[i].y);
        enemies2.add(s);
    }

}


public Level1State(GameStateManager gsm) {
    //graphics
    this.gsm = gsm;
    init();
}

public void update() {
    //enemy.update();
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        Enemy e = enemies.get(i);
        e.update();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<enemies2.size(); i++){
        Enemy2 e = enemies2.get(i);
        e.update();
    }
    // player.update();
    player.update();

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    // draw background
    bg.draw(g);

    // draw player
    player.draw(g);

    // draw enemies
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        enemies.get(i).draw(g);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < enemies2.size(); i++) {
        enemies2.get(i).draw(g);
    }
}

public void keyPressed(int k) {
    //all key settings
    if (k == KeyEvent.VK_D) {       
        player.setSpeedX(1);
    }
    if (k == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        player.setSpeedX(-1);
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        player.setSpeedY(-1);
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        player.setSpeedY(1);
    }

}

public void keyReleased(int k) {
    if (k == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        player.setSpeedX(0);
    }
    if (k == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        player.setSpeedX(0);
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        player.setSpeedY(0);
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        player.setSpeedY(0);
    }

}

public static Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

}
```

Sorry for the long post but wanted to get the whole code out there. Don't exactly know where the mistake is. I was editting in Eclipse and it doesn't give any errors so at the moment I am clueless. Would appreciate if someone had an idea what is going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something is null at line 29 in Level1State - which is line 29?

Comment: For future reference: Don't be afraid of the stack trace. Go to where it points you, figure out what is throwing the exception and for what reason and then fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

```
enemy.setMoveSpeed(-2);
enemy2.setMoveSpeed(2);
```

in your `Level1State` `init()` method. Problem is `enemy` and `enemy2` are both null at that stage which causes a `NullPointerException` to be thrown.

Try moving the above mentioned lines below

```
enemy = new Enemy("/Images/Square.png");
enemy2 = new Enemy2("/Images/Square.png");
```

Comment: Worked for me thanks. Changed those lines and it works fine now thanks.